# JavaScript: Append content as child of nextSibling

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying append to the next element of multiple divs. So far I have this:

**HTML**

```
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow></div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow></div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow></div>
```

After the function runs, the content should look like this:

```
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow><p class="content">My content</p></div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow><p class="content">My content</p></div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="yellow><p class="content">My content</p></div>
```

This is my function thus far:

```
var blue = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='blue']");

var next = blue.nextSibling;

for (var i=blue.length; i--;) {
    var insertdiv = document.createElement('p');
    insertdiv.className   = 'content';
    insertdiv.textContent = 'My Content';    

    next[i].parentNode.appendChild(insertdiv, blue[i]);
}
```

Can't get this to work properly though.

**No jQuery please.**

Comment: It looks like you have plenty of good answers.  But to be sure that they work, you should close the quotes on your `class="yellow` attributes.

Comment: Why don't you "get" the `.yellow` divs, and add elements to them, like I answered? You seem to have exactly the class you need already, no need to over-complicate getting the right element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There as several logical errors in your code. [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22983944/1249581) has described them perfectly.

However, in your case I would rather use CSS next sibling selector in `querySelectorAll`:

```
var next = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='blue'] + *");
for (var i = 0, len = next.length; i < len; i++) {
    var insertdiv = document.createElement('p');
    insertdiv.className   = 'content';
    insertdiv.textContent = 'My Content';
    next[i].appendChild(insertdiv);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8uywP/

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it. Never would have thought of that :)

Comment: I like this approach, +1.

Comment: Wow, that selector is expensive, though! http://jsperf.com/cost-of-selecting-next-sibling I was expecting to find that this would be better than doing my defensive check above (the `if (blues[i].nextSibling)`), but slower than assuming that the next sibling was there (e.g., because you know the structure of the HTML). But to my surprise, it's slower than either of them. It doesn't *matter*, but it's surprising. I bet we could improve the speed markedly if we used something more specific on the right-hand side (`pre.blue + div.yellow`), since selectors are processed right-to-left.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, which is odd. Referring to [this article](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) adjacent sibling selector shouldn't be that slow. I'm not sure that performance will increase too much if we stop using it in combination with attribute and universal selector. Theoretically it should, but practically it does not: http://jsperf.com/cost-of-selecting-next-sibling/2.

Comment: @VisioN: Indeed, it [only makes things worse](http://jsperf.com/cost-of-selecting-next-sibling/3). But again, it's not like it's likely to matter. Useful to know if one runs into a performance issue and sees the adjacent sibling bit, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting, but it seems that jQuery [is using](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L273) native [CSS siblings selector](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L133) in Sizzle.

Comment: @VisioN: You've lost me, I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, what I'm talking about is that jQuery team is using the native implementation besides they care about performance too much. If it is so, maybe there is something wrong with our tests and the canonical CSS selector is not that slow?.. or they also haven't expected the speed issue. Otherwise, yes, it shouldn't matter too much for the normal use.

Comment: @VisioN: As far as I can tell, the `rsibling` variable is there to identify sibling combinators in a selector string. Sizzle has to support combinators, of course; I don't think that's anything to do with using/not using the native support for it.

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll` returns a *list* of elements. That list doesn't have a `nextSibling` property, so your second line gives you `undefined` in `next`.

```
var blues, i, insertDiv;
blues = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='blue']");
for (i = 0; i < blues.length; ++i) {
    if (blues[i].nextSibling) {
        console.log(blues[i].nextElementSibling.tagName);
        insertDiv = document.createElement('p');
        insertDiv.className   = 'content';
        insertDiv.textContent = 'My Content';    
        blues[i].nextElementSibling.appendChild(insertDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3143218: There was a typo (`insertdiv` rather than `insertDiv`), and one wanted `nextElementSibling` rather than `nextSibling`. Working example: http://jsbin.com/lezohequ/1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add them to the `.yellow` divs? Like this:

```
var yellow = document.getElementsByClassName("yellow");

for (var i=0, l = yellow.length; i<l; i++) {
    var insertdiv = document.createElement('p');
    insertdiv.className   = 'content';
    insertdiv.textContent = 'My Content';    

    yellow[i].appendChild(insertdiv);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GXae7/)**

There is no need to "Traverse" the dom like that if you have a class available on the elements you need.

Comment: This would indeed be the simplest solution, provided the OP wants to process **all** of the `div.yellow` elements. I sort of assumed he/she didn't.